# Splitting files at specific points

Tags: python, split

I have a json file with multiple sentences each separated by brackets. All of these brackets are in one line. I need to make an individual file for each of the sentences enclosed in brackets. How would I do this in python?

Comment: you mean you have a list of dicts? then load it, then iterate & dump each dict in a separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking to do something like this for each part of the JSON:

```
for i in range(index+1, len(json)):
  line = json[i]

  file = open("jsonfile.txt","w")
  if line.find("{") >= 0:
    # write the sentences to a file
    if line.find("}") >= 0:
      break
    else:
      file.write(line)
```

Hopefully this helps you go in the right direction.